# Which type of motor use in oil-free air compressor? And how to detect stall?

Tags: ac-motor

I got 220V AC single-phase air compressor which labeled "Oil-free" and it look like this.
[image]

Some time the motor fail to start and got smoke out. (Some people says that happen when start motor with high air pressure in tank. Maybe start torque is too low to pump the air into pressurized tank.)

I called this situation as "Stall".

So my questions are.

1. Which type of motor used in that compressor? There are four wires, two for line and neutral, two for capacitor. I measure current about 3 A for L-N and 2.5 A for capacitor.
2. Any ideas how to detect or prevent stall? Can I just detect over-current using fuse or detect phase shift between 2-coil?

Comment: Any good compressor uses a bypass valve, the air is pumped in the tank only when motor gains rpm. Without that valve you can change motors for ever.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič  I already replaced one motor then this event seem to occur again. I really new for this. I got some background for electronics and physics please tell me more.

Comment: There are many different ways of building a compressor unit: check valve, unloader valve, cold start valve,...pressure switch, thermal protection switch,...You should see a working unit, search some forum where you could find specialist for that field. Your issue is related more to mechanical engineering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Any ideas how to detect or prevent stall? Can I just detect over-current using fuse...?"

Electric motors generally pull their stall current whenever they are starting up. The fuse would need to be a slower-blow type. Otherwise you will be replacing fuses, or resetting circuit breakers all the time. However, you are constrained by not wanting damage to your motor, which might happen in a matter of seconds. A more robust solution might be to detect the current, either with a sense resistor, or a Rogowski coil, connect it to a timer, and if the over-current lasts too long, fire an SCR crowbar circuit to blow the fuse. This, however, would be significantly more work, and whether it is worth the trouble depends upon the value of reliability in your situation.

Comment: You get motor-rated ("Class C" or even D) breakers which will allow higher current for a short time, then trip if the current doesn't reduce. Probably a good idea even if only as a backstop against other solutions.

Comment: Have you ever seen a compressor unit? You won't find anything you recommend on it. Things are much simpler, when done appropriate with a knowledge gained over last century.